# How to use memcpy to copy one array to another one?

Tags: c, memcpy

```
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
   L[i] = arr[l + i];
```

Because I want to copy a large array,I heard that need to use memcpy.

Comment: You can get a pointer to an arbitrary element at index `l` by using the address-of operator, as in `&arr[l]`. This could be used as the source argument for a `memcpy` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [memcpy with startIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163624/memcpy-with-startindex)

Comment: Adam's answer is of better quality. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

memcpy as the name says, copy memory area. is a `C` standard function under `string.h`.

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

#### description:

The `memcpy()` function copies `n` bytes from memory area `src` to memory
       area `dest`.  The memory areas `must not overlap`.  Use memmove(3) if the
       memory areas do overlap. The `memcpy()` function returns a `pointer to`dest.
for more details goto man7: [memcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

so in your case the call would be:

```
memcpy(L, &arr[l], n1*sizeof(arr[l]));
```

sizeof one array elementis:

```
sizeof(arr[l])
```

make sure that `(l+n1)` doesnot exceeds the array boundaries! its you responsibility.

Comment: @曾品翔, please accept my answer (by pushing the beside V ) if you find it useful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
memcopy(destination, source, length)
```

That would be in your case:

```
int len = sizeof(int) * n1;
memcopy(L, arr+l, len);
```

Note: You may have to fix the length calculation according to the type you are using. Moreover, you should also remember to add 1 to include the \0 character that terminates char arrays if you are dealing with strings.

Comment: If you use `sizeof (arr[0])` there is no more need to adjust according to type. And it's actually `memcpy`.

Comment: @Gerhardh yep, that's why I advised the OP to go for Adam's answer. I did not want to plagiarize his answer.